# Error: This expression has type (int * int) option but an expression was expected of type 'a * 'b

Tags: ocaml

If i put this code to utop line by line, then it works, but if I compile it as programm, then I see error.

```
module List = Core.Std.List;;

let () =
    let shifts  = [ (-1, -1); (0, -1) ] in
    let first = List.nth shifts 0 in
    let (a, b) = first in
    Printf.printf "%d %d\n" a b;
;;
```

And error message:

```
Error: This expression has type (int * int) option
       but an expression was expected of type 'a * 'b
```

What wrong with types and why it works in utop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like `Core.Std.List.nth` has the type `'a list -> int -> 'a option` in order to handle the case when the int is out of range. The standard library `List.nth` has the type `'a list -> int -> 'a`. It raises an exception for an out-of-range int.

If you're using `Core.Std.List` in one case but the standard `List` in the other, this would explain the difference.

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot about two versions of List. It seems like always use `open Core.Std` it is better than open only one name from it. The reason why I import only List - in my code I use Array.make and this method do not exist in Core.Std.Array.

Comment: @grigoriytretyakov there is `Array.create` in Core that does exactly the same. Yes, it is better to always `open Core.Std`. In such case, you can use `Caml` module to access the standard library, like `Caml.Array.make`.